# Post data from excel spreadsheet-arcampdesktop- arccollector

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel

I recently created a excel spreadsheet with different webcams that have lat long, name and hyperlink for each angle on every camera. I am able to import that data from excel to arcmap desktop no problem, but when I transfer the data from the desktop to arccollector or AGOL all the attributes on the table are blank and does not show the symbol I created on the desktop.